# Открыть страницу (просмотр кода страницы) с помощью консоли

Tags: javascript

Можно ли через консоль браузера открыть эту же страницу только с ее кодом? 
Как будто перед url поставить

```
view-source:
```

и заново вызвать страницу.

Comment: Можно попробовать так `window.location.href = 'view-source:' + window.location.href`

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделать редирект используя объект `window.location`:

```
window.location.href = 'view-source:' + window.location.href
```